# Text manipulation problem - how to replace text after a known value

Tags: regex, text, powershell, file-manipulation

I have a large text file containing filenames ending in .txt
Some of the rows of the file have unwanted text after the filename extension.
I am trying to find a way to search+replace or trim the whole file so that if a row is found with .txt, anything after this is simply removed. Example

> C:\Test1.txt
>
> C:\Test2.txtHelloWorld this is my
>   problem
>
> C:\Test3.txt_***_*__**_Annoying
>   stuff1234 .r

Desired result

> C:\Test1.txt
>
> C:\Test2.txt
>
> C:\Test3.txt

I have tried with notepad++, or using batch/powershell, but got close, no cigar.

```
(Get-Content "D:\checkthese.txt") | 
Foreach-Object {$_ -replace '.txt*', ".txt"} | 
Set-Content "D:\CLEAN.txt"
```

My thinking here is if I replace anything (Wildcard*) after .txt then I would trim off what I need, but this doesnt work. I think I need to use regular expression, buy have the syntax wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply change the `*` to a `.*`, like so:

```
(Get-Content "D:\checkthese.txt") | 
Foreach-Object {$_ -replace '\.txt.*', ".txt"} | 
Set-Content "D:\CLEAN.txt"
```

In regular expressions, `*` means "0 or more times", and in this case it'd act on the final `t` of `.txt`, so `.txt*` would only match `.tx`, `.txt`, `.txtt`, `.txttt`, etc...

`.`, however, matches any character. This means, `.*` matches 0 or more of anything, which is what you want. Because of this, I also escaped the `.` in `.txt`, as it otherwise could break on filenames like: `alovelytxtfile.txt`, which would be trimmed to `alovel.txt`.

For more information, see:

- [Regex Tutorial - `.`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html)
- [Regex Tutorial - `*`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)

Comment: That works nicely and thanks for the second hint at escaping the "." I would not have noticed that, cheers!

Comment: Let me point out that your example is wrong. If you didn't escape the `.` at the beginning of your regex, it would cause the returned example file name to be `alovel.txt`, not `alovelytxt`. A quibble to an otherwise fine answer. ;-)